# MongoDB Array of Locations return only matched location

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, geospatial

To give an example scenario... Lets say we have a MongoDB collection of companies. Each company document can have multiple addresses (stored in an array of Addresses). I want to search for companies that are near my location, but only show the address matched by the $geoNear operator, not all the other Address array members.

I'm trying something like:

```
db.Companies.aggregate(
        { 
            '$geoNear': { 
                near: [ -77.3898602, 38.8735614], 
                distanceField: 'dist.Distance', 
                maxDistance: 0.02020712301086133,
                spherical: true, 
                distanceMultiplier: 4948.75,
                includeLocs: "dist.location"
                } 
        })
```

This gives me the coordinates of the array member that was used to calculate the distance, but I really just want only the parent document minus the address array members that weren't matched.

Any ideas or tips??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Perform a Count

The following example selects documents to process using the $match pipeline operator and then pipes the results to the $group pipeline operator to compute a count of the documents:

```
db.articles.aggregate( [
                        { $match : { score : { $gt : 70, $lte : 90 } } },
                        { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
                       ] );
```

In the aggregation pipeline, $match selects the documents where the score is greater than 70 and less than or equal to 90. These documents are then piped to the $group to perform a count. The aggregation returns the following:

```
{
  "result" : [
               {
                 "_id" : null,
                 "count" : 3
               }
             ],
  "ok" : 1
}
```